# how do i create a merge request from a fork in gitlab

Tags: git, merge, version-control, request, gitlab

I joined a project on which I've done some work. The work has now been validated and I need to create a merge request (back to master) from the changes I have pushed to my fork. But I don't understand how I can do this in gitlab...Can anybody help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To create a merge request to merge branch from forked repo into the branch of the upstream repo, you can use below steps:

In the forked repo -> Merge Requests -> select the branch from forked repo as the source branch, and select branch from the upstream repo as target branch -> Compare branches -> Specify the user Assign to -> Submit merge request.

More details, you can refer the document [Merging upstream](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/forking_workflow.html#merging-upstream).

Comment: broken link.  New location I believe is: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/forking_workflow.html#merging-upstream

Comment: What if the forked repo is a private fork? How does the MR is done then?